# the edit button not active (form not pop out)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Why the form not pop out when I click the edit button

My console has displayed the captured line, but the form cannot jump out! [web pic](https://ibb.co/0ZmknvF)

- the code

I did write the function, might be the naming issue, but I couldn't correct it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Server Management</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
   
</head>
<body>

      <main id="main-holder">

    
    </main>   
  


    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <!-- <script defer src="login-page.js"></script> -->
  
  
 

  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
  <table id="example_02" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <script>
var Selected_add_edit_api; 

    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/server/s_rvs",   // with rvs ,and svr
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.servers);
            return response.servers
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_table_edit" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' ;
            }
          },
 
          
          { data: "name", title: "Name" },
          { data: "send_subject", title: "To Subject" },
          { data: "listen_subject", title: "Listen Subject" },
              
          {
            data: null,
            title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn custom-btn" id="AlarmEvent_Setting_table" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_table_000" data-whatever=" ">...</button>' ;
            }
          },
          { data: "status", title: "Status" },
          { data: "rvs_enable", title: "Enable" },       

        ]
      });



      var table2 = $("#example_02").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/server/s_svr",   // with rvs ,abd svr
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.servers);
            return response.servers
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data_table2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_table2_edit" data-whatever=" ">Edit2</button>' ;
            }
          },

          
          { data: "name", title: "Name" },
          { data: "ip", title: "Hostname/IP" },
          { data: "port", title: "Port" },
          { data: "url", title: "URL" },       
          
          {
            data: null,
            title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn custom-btn" id="Alarm_Event_Setting_table2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_table2_000" data-whatever=" ">...</button>' ;
            }
          },
          { data: "status", title: "Status" }, 
          { data: "svr_enable", title: "Enable" },       

        ]
      });




      table.draw()
      table2.draw()


      // Edit row function

      var rowData; 
      

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;
  
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });

      $('#example_02 tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


      var data = table2.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
      rowData = data;

      console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });

      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal_table_edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        // modal.find('.modal-title').text('Data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data02" || button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data" ) {        
          inputFields.val("");
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add Data ' + recipient);
          Selected_add_edit_api = "add-api";                                               
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Data ' + recipient);
            Selected_add_edit_api = "edit-api";                                       
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });

    
    $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal_table_000').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        // modal.find('.modal-title').text('Data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data02" || button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data" ) {        
          inputFields.val("");
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add Data ' + recipient);
          Selected_add_edit_api = "add-api";                                               
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Data ' + recipient);
            Selected_add_edit_api = "edit-api";                                        //// 
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });

    
    $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal_table2_edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        // modal.find('.modal-title').text('Data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data02" || button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data" ) {        
          inputFields.val("");
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add Data ' + recipient);
          Selected_add_edit_api = "add-api";                                               
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Data ' + recipient);
            Selected_add_edit_api = "edit-api";                                  
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });

    
    $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal_table2_000').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        // modal.find('.modal-title').text('Data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data02" || button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data" ) {       
          inputFields.val("");
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add Data ' + recipient);
          Selected_add_edit_api = "add-api";                                               
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Data ' + recipient);
            Selected_add_edit_api = "edit-api";                                      
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });




      function editRow_website(id){
        
        
            
        var device_id=document.getElementById("device_id"+id);  
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);  
        var group=document.getElementById("group"+id);
        var ip=document.getElementById("ip"+id);
        var port=document.getElementById("port"+id);
        var ipc_enable=document.getElementById("ipc_enable"+id);
        var ftp_enable=document.getElementById("ftp_enable"+id);
        var id=document.getElementById("id"+id);
        var created_at=document.getElementById("created_at"+id);
        var updated_at=document.getElementById("updated_at"+id);
        
        let getEditData = {
          "device_id": device_id,
          "email_data": name,
          "address_data": group,
          "name_data": ip,
          "email_data": port,
          "address_data": ipc_enable,
          "name_data": ftp_enable,
          "email_data": id,
          "address_dat": created_at,
          "address_dat": updated_at,
        }

        document.getElementById("#editid input").value = device_id
       
      }
      
 

    });




  </script>

<style>
  .custom-btn {
    background-color: #c3c6cb;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  </style>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class ="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="#exampleModal_table_edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">device_id:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_To_Subject" class="col-form-label">To Subject:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_To_Subject">
            </div>
            
            <!-- Additional form fields -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field1" class="col-form-label">Listen Subject:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_Listen_Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field2" class="col-form-label">Enable :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_Enable">
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script>
   


    function editRow_rvs(data) {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)
    
      //// EDIT api ///
      console.log("EDIT=====", data);
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/server/rvs",   /// api change /// RVS
        type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', charset=utf-8'
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
        },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("SUCCESS",response);
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      })
      // .then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }

      
    function editRow_svr(data) {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)
    
      //// EDIT api ///
      console.log("EDIT=====", data);
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/server/svr",   /// api change /// RVS
        type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', // 不能用 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , // 不用JSON.stringify()
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  // 只要call api 要加header 的授權
        },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("SUCCESS",response);
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      })
      // .then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }

    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal_table_edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal_table_edit').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }

    
    </script>

  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem") || [];
    
    function save(data) {
      // var getData = document.getElementById("#sendData form").val
      var itemValue_edit_name = document.getElementById("input_edit_name").value || "";
      var itemValue_To_Subject = document.getElementById("input_To_Subject").value || "";
      var itemValue_Listen_Subject = document.getElementById("input_Listen_Subject").value || "";
      var itemValue_edit_Enable = document.getElementById("input_edit_Enable").value || "";



      console.log("itemValue_edit_name", itemValue_edit_name, typeof(itemValue_edit_name));
      console.log("itemValue_To_Subject", itemValue_To_Subject, typeof(itemValue_To_Subject));
      console.log("itemValue_Listen_Subject", itemValue_Listen_Subject, typeof(itemValue_Listen_Subject));
      console.log("itemValue_edit_Enable", itemValue_edit_Enable, typeof(itemValue_edit_Enable));


      

      let send_Edit_API_Data = {
        name:itemValue_edit_name,
        send_subject:itemValue_To_Subject,
        listen_subject: itemValue_Listen_Subject,
        rvs_enable:itemValue_edit_Enable,

      }

      
      if (Selected_add_edit_api === "add-api") {
      AddRow(send_Edit_API_Data); 
      console.log("send_Add_API_Data", send_Edit_API_Data);

    } else if (Selected_add_edit_api === "edit-api") {
      editRow_rvs(send_Edit_API_Data); 
      editRow_svr(send_Edit_API_Data); // run editRow
      console.log("send_Edit_API_Data", send_Edit_API_Data);

    } else {
      console.log("Invalid value for Selected_add_edit_api");
    }
  
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am genuinely new to website development and I have recently started learning about AJAX, jQuery, and other related technologies. I acknowledge that I still have a lot of room for improvement in these areas.

I would sincerely appreciate any assistance or guidance that can be offered to help me enhance my skills and understanding.

Comment: You have console errors. `contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', charset=utf-8'` is an invalid string. You likely want to remove the last `charset=utf-8'` including the quote
You should consolidate the script in ONE place and not in several script tags around the document.. What is is script.js for example? Style tags belong in the heeada.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because on initialization of the layout the buttons does not exsists, so the event fo clicking to open the modal can't be bound by bootstrap.
To work this around you could try something like this:

```js
 $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


      var data = table2.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
      rowData = data;

      console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      $('#exampleModal_table_edit').modal('show')
});
```